# Getting NoSuchElementException when doing filter findFirst

Tags: filter, java-8, nosuchelementexception, findfirst

I keep on getting  'java.util.NoSuchElementException: No value present' when executing filter findFirst.
I can't change the code much as it will break other part of code and we dont want to write method logic inside filter.
Code give is below.

**--- I am getting below error when calling the method**

**Error :**

```
java.util.NoSuchElementException: No value present
        at java.util.Optional.get(Optional.java:135)
```

The error is because the value is null for " .filter(x -> x > 5)
                    .findFirst()"

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Integer> list = Arrays.asList(1, 10, 3, 7, 5);
        int a = list.stream()
                   // .peek(num -> System.out.println("will filter " + num))
                .filter(x -> x== null)
                .map( t -> {
                    System.out.println("hello");
                    return 0;
                })
                    .filter(x -> x > 5)
                    .findFirst()
                    .get();
        System.out.println(a);
```

Here list.stream() will give stream which will be use by .filter(x -> x== null).
Now in this scenario x is not null so when it come to .filter(x -> x > 5) it give null because stream is not there.
Hence the exception.

I need help in some alternative for this.

Comment: The `Optional` returned by `.findFirst()` can be empty. That means, no match has been found. That may happen when `source.getTrans()` returns an empty collection or `null` (as you map `null` to an empty set explicitly), or if the `filter` predicates did not accept anything. Mind that your stream only accepts elements for which `.getDType() == null` *and* `.getD() != null`. Generally, you should not call `get()` on an `Optional` without checking whether a value is present. When it is, your subsequent tests (besides mixing up the `trans` variable and the `EmployeeTransaction` type) are redundant

Comment: Yes, but in this case source.getTrans() has value

Comment: Have you got a class **and** a variable both called `EmployeeTransaction`?

Comment: you can use this example,

Comment: You can use this example 2 from above please. I will edit the description.

Comment: Are you asking for an alternative to the `get()` call because it's throwing an exception? Why not `orElse(...)`?

Comment: No, when debug the code this value is null " .filter(x -> x > 5)
                    .findFirst()" . Ideally it should not be. I need to figure out an alternate approach for this code so that error does not show up.

Comment: You're filtering out every element with `.filter(x -> x== null)`, there's nothing left after that. Then you map every element to 0 and filter by `x > 5`, which would also filter out every element if there were any left. What are you expecting this code to do?

Comment: I am expecting this code to print 10.

Comment: Why should it print ten? Your first `.filter(x -> x== null)` doesn’t let `10` pass.

Comment: Yes, so i am trying to fix it. The requirement is when list is not null it should print 10 from values and when it is null then map should be invoked.

Answer (score 0):

This will print 10 as expected, or "Null" if the list is empty:

```
List<Integer> list = Arrays.asList(1, 10, 3, 7, 5);
Optional<Integer> a = list.stream()
        .filter(x -> x > 5)
        .findFirst();
System.out.println(a.isPresent() ? a.get() : "Null");
```

You don't want to use the `map` method here, that's used to apply an operation to each element and replace it with the result. For example, `.map(x -> x + 3)` would change `[1, 10, 3, 7, 5]` into `[4, 13, 6, 10, 8]`. You can't tell whether the stream is empty or not from an intermediate operation like `map`, you need to use a terminal operation like `findFirst` and look at the result.

Comment: Thanks, but in cases when list is empty then this will break.

Comment: @Rahul I added a few possible ways to handle empty lists.

Comment: Thanks but i had to invoke below in case of NULL..
 map( t -> {
      System.out.println("Null");
      return 0;